# Discord bot not coming online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I recently made a discord bot but it wont come online there are no errors also idk why this is my code.

```
const TOKEN = "MyBotsToken";
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('./client/Client');
const {
    prefix,
    token,
} = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

console.log(client.commands);

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
    console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    try {
        if(commandName == "ban" || commandName == "userinfo") {
            command.execute(message, client);
        } else {
            command.execute(message);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }

    console.log("bot is ready for use")

    bot.login(MyBotsToken);
});
```

My bot is also using node.js and javascript. I have also tried node index.js in cmd. nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else
nothing else

Thanks
Extremepro999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `login` action is within your `onMessage` event.

That means it will only be used when your bot detects a message. Since it won't go online it can't detect a message and so on...

Good news is that you can fix this simply by putting `bot.login(MyBotsToken);` outside of the `onReady` event. What you also need to do is use `.login()` on your client object.

So it should look like this.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    // your code
})

client.login(MyBotsToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

`bot.login(MyBotsToken)` should be outside of `client.on('message', async message => {});`